# How to dynamically delete multiple rows in Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a 3d array-DataSeries in JavaScript, the row index is from 0 to DataSeries.length-1;

I have another 1d array, this array is a subset of the above 3d array-DataSeries row indexs collection.

For example DataSeries row index is from 0 to 7, the 1d array is{2,3,4}.

What I wanna do is keep the DataSeries rows which the row number are in the 1d array, and delete rows which the row numbers are not in the 1d array.

Thus, for the above example, I need to keep the DataSeries[2],DataSeries[3],DataSeries[4];
and delete the rows DataSeries[0],DataSeries[1],DataSeries[5],DataSeries[6],DataSeries[7]

Thanks!

Comment: You should simplify the problem and provide some code.

Comment: Agreed, @wared . . . code and/or sample data would be **very** helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking.

```
var a1dArray = [2, 3, 4],
    a3dArray = [],
    filtered,
    row,
    x,
    y,
    z;

// the fact that you have a 3d array is irrelavant to the question, but here we go
for (x = 0; x < 8; x += 1) {
    a3dArray[x] = [];
    for (y = 0; y < 1; y += 1) {
        a3dArray[x][y] = [];
        for (z = 0; z < 1; z += 1) {
            a3dArray[x][y][z] = Math.random();
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a3dArray));

// new array with only the rows defined in a1dArray
filtered = a3dArray.filter(function(subArray, index) {
    return a1dArray.indexOf(index) === -1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));

// modify the original a3dArray and leave only the rows in a1dArray
for (row = a3dArray.length - 1; row >= 0; row -= 1) {
    if (a1dArray.indexOf(row) !== -1) {
        a3dArray.splice(row, 1);
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a3dArray));
```

Output

```
[[[0.743774963542819]],[[0.7655636318959296]],[[0.8409351697191596]],[[0.6550902314484119]],[[0.7819186896085739]],[[0.43656325968913734]],[[0.048759558936581016]]]
[[[0.743774963542819]],[[0.7655636318959296]],[[0.43656325968913734]],[[0.048759558936581016]]] 
[[[0.743774963542819]],[[0.7655636318959296]],[[0.43656325968913734]],[[0.048759558936581016]]]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hS6H9/)

Comment: I made some changes based on ur code. Take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to remove some rows from a javascript array :

```
var a = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
while (a.length > 1) {
    a.splice(a.length - 1, 1)
}
a; // [[1, 2, 3]]
```